# Hyper-V machine sometimes gets stuck when enabling wsl2 (nested virtualization enabled)

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v, wsl2

I have a machine running a windows 11 VM with nested virtualization enabled.
when enabling wsl2 features and restarting the VM sometimes "halts" in the reboot process. seemingly for no reason. other times (I have a checkpoint) however it works just fine.

In general nested virtualization seem to be unstable.

This VM is intended for software testing (required to be run on windows and wsl) and I would like it to not be run on a dedicated machine despite it being an easy solution.

Any hints or diagnosis would help.